# Executar macro ao selecionar item em célula com validação de dados

Tags: vba, validação, macro

Olá, Preciso executar uma macro que atualiza os dados sempre que for selecionado um item na célula (com validação de dados).
É a mesma macro que faz a pesquisa em um BD de acordo com o valor da célula.

Estou estudando sobre o evento worksheet_change, mas não está dando certo.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Reformulando...

Tenho uma macro que precisa ser executada quando eu selecionar um item em uma célula com validação de dados. Já utilizei vários exemplos com o evento worksheet_change mas não funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qualquer que seja sua rotina de atualização de dados, o que você não especificou, pode ser executada utilizando este trecho de código, que avalia uma célula que possui validação de dados. Uma vez escolhido um item válido, o evento Change da guia de planilha, onde este trecho deve ser colocado, é executado.

```
Option Explicit

Dim varValorAntigoDaCélulaL13 As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngValidada As Excel.Range

    Set rngValidada = Range("L13") 'célula possui Validação de Dados.
    
    If varValorAntigoDaCélulaL13 <> rngValidada.Value Then
            varValorAntigoDaCélulaL13 = rngValidada.Value
            MsgBox "Coloque a chamada para sua rotina de atualização de dados aqui."
    End If

End Sub
```